# How to display letters on an image using C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building an application with C# WPF. And I'm using MVVM architecture. I want to display some letters on an image in the given coordinates. So far, the only thing I was able to do is to render some shapes like rectangles using 'Geometry' class.

I have attached an image for references.
[image: This is what I need]

The grid is an image(a PNG file)

And below is my current code for the view model and XAML file.

ViewModel

```
public class InspectionGridViewModel : RegionViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Drawing> Drawings { get; set; }

    public InspectionGridViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, ILogger<InspectionGridViewModel> logger, MainModuleConfiguration configuration) : base(regionManager, logger)
    {
        PlotMarkersInTheGrid();
    }

    public void PlotMarkersInTheGrid()
    {
        Drawings = new ObservableCollection<Drawing>();
        Drawings.Add(new Drawing
        {
            Geometry = new StreamGeometry(),
            Fill = Brushes.LightBlue,
            Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        });
        Drawings.Add(new Drawing
        {
            Geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(50, 150, 100, 60)),
            Fill = Brushes.LightGreen,
            Stroke = Brushes.Green,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        });
    }
}

public class Drawing
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
    public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }
}
```

XAML file

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Drawings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
              Fill="{Binding Fill}"
              Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
              StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

First thing I wanna know. Is this possible to do? If so, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about rather than messing with geometry, you use `TextBlock` and use a `ViewBox` to scale it? You could just place these in a `Canvas` similiar to what you're attempting to do with those geometry items. So, your XAML would be very similiar to what you already have, but template the items into a `ViewBox`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Markers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox Width="{Binding Size}" Height="{Binding Size}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MarkerText}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PosX}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PosY}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that a `ItemContainerStyle` is used for positioning since the direct child of the canvas is required to use the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.

With that in place and view models like these ..

```
public class InspectionGridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MarkerViewModel> Markers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MarkerViewModel>();

    public InspectionGridViewModel()
    {
        Markers = new ObservableCollection<MarkerViewModel>()
        {
            new MarkerViewModel()
            {
                MarkerText = "A",
                Size = 50,
                PosX = 10,
                PosY = 20
            },
            new MarkerViewModel()
            {
                MarkerText = "B",
                Size = 100,
                PosX = 80,
                PosY = 50
            }
        };
    }
}

public class MarkerViewModel
{
    public string MarkerText { get; set; }
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following result. I think this is what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This works as expected.